# PMD 3.2.6 Issue With Eclipse 3.2

Tags: eclipse, view, rad, pmd

I have installed PMD 3.2.6 plugin on eclipse 3.2 using the steps mentioned in
http://pmd.sourceforge.net/integrations.html#eclipse

However, I get following error if I try to open the PMD views or try to PMD code check.
Note that I did re-start my eclipse after installation.
Also it worked fine when I installed it in Eclipse 3.3. Unfortunately I have to stick to Eclipse 3.2 due to some other constraints.

```
Error: Unable to create view: An unexpected exception was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.ui.views.PriorityFilter.<init>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.pmd.eclipse.ui.views.ViolationOverview.init(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart.init(ViewPart.java:122)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:305)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:197)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:566)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:3915)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.restoreState(WorkbenchPage.java:2929)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.restoreState(WorkbenchWindow.java:1936)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.doRestoreState(Workbench.java:2873)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$14(Workbench.java:2821)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$20.run(Workbench.java:1697)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runStartupWithProgress(Workbench.java:1437)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.restoreState(Workbench.java:1695)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$12(Workbench.java:1666)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$18.run(Workbench.java:1545)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:37)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.restoreState(Workbench.java:1489)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchConfigurer.restoreState(WorkbenchConfigurer.java:183)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:702)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.init(Workbench.java:1101)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:1863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:422)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEApplication.run(IDEApplication.java:95)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:336)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:280)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:977)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:952)
```

Anyone faced this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

That's an old version of Eclipse!  If PMD isn't supported with that version, you can run PMD at the command line or as an Ant script.  Then the plugin integration fails to be a factor.